# Pick random word from list?

Tags: c#, list

I´m having trouble picking a random word from a list in another file.
Actually I can´t even get it to choose any word. I´m not sure how to connect the 2 files so to say.
Hoping someone can help out, I´m a beginner so please explain as easy as possible:)

I have 2 files, one is called program.cs and the other is called WordList.cs
I´m gonna paste all my code but first the little snip that I´m having problem with. I just can´t figure out how to write the code correct.

Here is the little part which is called Pick word:

```
 //PICK WORD

    static string pickWord()
    {
        string returnword = "";

        TextReader file = new StreamReader(words);
        string fileLine = file.ReadLine();


        Random randomGen = new Random();
        returnword = words[randomGen.Next(0, words.Count - 1)];
        return returnword;
    }
```

And here is all the code in Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class Hangman
{

    static void Main(string[] args)                                                  
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Title = "C# Hangman";
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome To C# Hangman!");

        //MENU
        int MenuChoice = 0;
        while (MenuChoice != 4)
        {

        Console.Write("\n\t1) Add words");
        Console.Write("\n\t2) Show list of words");
        Console.Write("\n\t3) Play");
        Console.Write("\n\t4) Quit\n\n");

        Console.Write("\n\tChoose 1-4: ");        //Choose meny item

        MenuChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        WordList showing = new WordList();

        switch (MenuChoice)
        {
            case 1:               
                Console.Write("\n\tAdd a word\n\n");
                var insert = Console.ReadLine();
                showing.AddWord(insert);
                Console.Write("\n\tList of words\n\n");
                showing.ListOfWords();                
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.Write("\n\tList of words\n\n");
                showing.ListOfWords();
                break;


            case 3:   //Running game

                int numGuessesInt = -1;

                while (numGuessesInt == -1)
                {
                    /* Sets the number of guesses the user has to guess the word*/
                    pickNumGuesses(ref numGuessesInt);
                }

                /* Randomly picks a word*/
                string word = pickWord();


                /* Creates a list of characters that will show */
                List<char> guessedLetters = new List<char>();
                bool solved = false;
                while (solved == false)
                {
                    /* Displaying a string to the user based on the user's correct guesses.
                     * If nothing is correct string will return "_ _ _ " */
                    string wordToDisplay = displayWord(guessedLetters, word);
                    /* If the string returned contains the "_" character, all the
                    * correct letters have not been guessed, so checking if user
                    * has lost, by checking if numGuessesLeft is less than 1.*/
                    if (!wordToDisplay.Contains("_"))
                    {
                        solved = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("You Win!  The word was " + word);
                        /* Check if the user wants to play again.  If they do,
                        * then solved is set to true, will end the loop,
                        * otherwise, checkIfPlayAgain will close the program.*/
                        checkIfPlayAgain();
                    }
                    else if (numGuessesInt <= 0)
                    {
                        solved = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("You Lose!  The word was " + word);
                        checkIfPlayAgain();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* If the user has not won or lost, call guessLetter,
                        * display the word, minus guesses by 1*/
                        guessLetter(guessedLetters, word, wordToDisplay, ref numGuessesInt);
                    }
                }

                    break;

            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tEnd game?\n\n");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, invalid selection");
                break;  
        }

        }

    }

    // ****** PICK NUMBER OF GUESSES ******

    static void pickNumGuesses(ref int numGuessesInt)
    {
        string numGuessesString = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Pick a number of guesses");
        numGuessesString = Console.ReadLine();
        try
        {
            numGuessesInt = Convert.ToInt32(numGuessesString);
            if (!(numGuessesInt <= 20 & numGuessesInt >= 1))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            numGuessesInt = -1;
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid Number of Guesses");
        }
    }

    //PICK WORD

    static string pickWord()
    {
        string returnword = "";

        TextReader file = new StreamReader(words);
        string fileLine = file.ReadLine();


        Random randomGen = new Random();
        returnword = words[randomGen.Next(0, words.Count - 1)];
        return returnword;
    }


    // ****** Display word ******

    static string displayWord(List<char> guessedCharacters, string word)
    {
        string returnedWord = "";
        if (guessedCharacters.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach (char letter in word)
            {
                returnedWord += "_ ";
            }
            return returnedWord;
        }
        foreach (char letter in word)
        {
            bool letterMatch = false;
            foreach (char character in guessedCharacters)
            {
                if (character == letter)
                {
                    returnedWord += character + " ";
                    letterMatch = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    letterMatch = false;
                }
            }
            if (letterMatch == false)
            {
                returnedWord += "_ ";
            }
        }
        return returnedWord;
    }


    // ****** Guess letter ******

    static void guessLetter(List<char> guessedCharacters, string word, string wordToDisplay, ref int numGuessesLeft)
    {
        string letters = "";
        foreach (char letter in guessedCharacters)
        {
            letters += " " + letter;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a letter");
        Console.WriteLine("Guessed Letters: " + letters);
        Console.WriteLine("Guesses Left: " + numGuessesLeft);
        Console.WriteLine(wordToDisplay);
        string guess = Console.ReadLine();
        char guessedLetter = 'a';
        try
        {
            guessedLetter = Convert.ToChar(guess);
            if (!Char.IsLetter(guessedLetter))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid Letter Choice");
            //guessLetter(guessedCharacters, word, wordToDisplay, ref numGuessesLeft);
        }
        bool repeat = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < guessedCharacters.Count; i++)
        {
            if (guessedCharacters[i] == guessedLetter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid Letter Choice");
                repeat = true;
                //guessLetter(guessedCharacters, word, wordToDisplay, ref numGuessesLeft);
            }
        }
        if (repeat == false)
        {
            guessedCharacters.Add(guessedLetter);
            numGuessesLeft -= 1;
        }
    }

    // ****** Check to see if player wants to play again. ******

    static void checkIfPlayAgain()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (y/n)");
        string playAgain = Console.ReadLine();
        if (playAgain == "n")
        {
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for WordList.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class WordList
{
    List <string> words = new List<string>();

    public void ListOfWords()
    {
        words.Add("test");         // Contains: test
        words.Add("dog");          // Contains: test, dog
        words.Insert(1, "shit"); // Contains: test, shit, dog

        words.Sort();
        foreach (string word in words) // Display for verification
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);

        }

    }

    public void AddWord(string value){
        words.Add(value);
      }
}
```

Comment: How the words are saved in file? Line by line, with spaces, or something else?

Comment: Add all your word choices to an instance of `List<string>`. Using an instance of the `Random` object, generate random numbers and index into the list to get a random word. What can be easier?

Comment: It´s the file above called WordList.cs. So it´s just a simple little List not from txt file...

Comment: But I have them in a List in the WordList.cs file. I don´t get how to get the 2 files connected, how to pick out one word. I managed to write out the list of words but not one... @Pieter Geerkens

Comment: In reading your comments, you mention your list of Words is supposed to be in a separate file all of these solutions are using a separate class not necessarily another file, how exactly is your question worded?

Comment: @MarkHall they are suppose to be in their own class and object but also in another file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code. The code works now but is far from perfect. 
Your solution has two files `Program.cs` and `Wordlist.cs`, which looks like this

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public class Hangman
{
    /* 
     * Some notes on your code:
     *   use naming convention for methods and fields, i.e. methods names start with a capital letter
     *   use modifiers for methods, i.e private, public, protected in your method declarations
     *   make variables private if you use them on several methods
     *   and finally: read a book on c#
     *   
     */

    private static WordList words;
    private static Random randomGen = new Random();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Title = "C# Hangman";
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome To C# Hangman!");
        initializeWordList();

        //MENU
        int MenuChoice = 0;
        while (MenuChoice != 4)
        {

            Console.Write("\n\t1) Add words");
            Console.Write("\n\t2) Show list of words");
            Console.Write("\n\t3) Play");
            Console.Write("\n\t4) Quit\n\n");

            Console.Write("\n\tChoose 1-4: ");        //Choose meny item

            MenuChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (MenuChoice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Write("\n\tAdd a word\n\n");
                    var insert = Console.ReadLine();
                    words.Add(insert);
                    Console.Write("\n\tList of words\n\n");
                    foreach (string w in words) // Display for verification
                        Console.WriteLine(w);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.Write("\n\tList of words\n\n");
                    foreach (string w in words) // Display for verification
                        Console.WriteLine(w);
                    break;


                case 3:   //Running game

                    int numGuessesInt = -1;

                    while (numGuessesInt == -1)
                    {
                        /* Sets the number of guesses the user has to guess the word*/
                        pickNumGuesses(ref numGuessesInt);
                    }

                    /* Randomly picks a word*/
                    string word = PickWord();


                    /* Creates a list of characters that will show */
                    List<char> guessedLetters = new List<char>();
                    bool solved = false;
                    while (solved == false)
                    {
                        /* Displaying a string to the user based on the user's correct guesses.
                         * If nothing is correct string will return "_ _ _ " */
                        string wordToDisplay = displayWord(guessedLetters, word);
                        /* If the string returned contains the "_" character, all the
                        * correct letters have not been guessed, so checking if user
                        * has lost, by checking if numGuessesLeft is less than 1.*/
                        if (!wordToDisplay.Contains("_"))
                        {
                            solved = true;
                            Console.WriteLine("You Win!  The word was " + word);
                            /* Check if the user wants to play again.  If they do,
                            * then solved is set to true, will end the loop,
                            * otherwise, checkIfPlayAgain will close the program.*/
                            checkIfPlayAgain();
                        }
                        else if (numGuessesInt <= 0)
                        {
                            solved = true;
                            Console.WriteLine("You Lose!  The word was " + word);
                            checkIfPlayAgain();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            /* If the user has not won or lost, call guessLetter,
                            * display the word, minus guesses by 1*/
                            guessLetter(guessedLetters, word, wordToDisplay, ref numGuessesInt);
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tEnd game?\n\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, invalid selection");
                    break;
            }

        }

    }


    private static void initializeWordList()
    {
        words = new WordList();
        words.Add("test");         // Contains: test
        words.Add("dog");          // Contains: test, dog
        words.Insert(1, "shit"); // Contains: test, shit, dog
        words.Sort();
    }


    // ****** PICK NUMBER OF GUESSES ******

    private static void pickNumGuesses(ref int numGuessesInt)
    {
        string numGuessesString = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Pick a number of guesses");
        numGuessesString = Console.ReadLine();
        try
        {
            numGuessesInt = Convert.ToInt32(numGuessesString);
            if (!(numGuessesInt <= 20 & numGuessesInt >= 1))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            numGuessesInt = -1;
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid Number of Guesses");
        }
    }

    //PICK WORD

    private static string PickWord()
    {
        return words[randomGen.Next(0, words.Count() - 1)];
    }


    // ****** Display word ******

    private static string displayWord(List<char> guessedCharacters, string word)
    {
        string returnedWord = "";
        if (guessedCharacters.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach (char letter in word)
            {
                returnedWord += "_ ";
            }
            return returnedWord;
        }
        foreach (char letter in word)
        {
            bool letterMatch = false;
            foreach (char character in guessedCharacters)
            {
                if (character == letter)
                {
                    returnedWord += character + " ";
                    letterMatch = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    letterMatch = false;
                }
            }
            if (letterMatch == false)
            {
                returnedWord += "_ ";
            }
        }
        return returnedWord;
    }


    // ****** Guess letter ******

    static void guessLetter(List<char> guessedCharacters, string word, string wordToDisplay, ref int numGuessesLeft)
    {
        string letters = "";
        foreach (char letter in guessedCharacters)
        {
            letters += " " + letter;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a letter");
        Console.WriteLine("Guessed Letters: " + letters);
        Console.WriteLine("Guesses Left: " + numGuessesLeft);
        Console.WriteLine(wordToDisplay);
        string guess = Console.ReadLine();
        char guessedLetter = 'a';
        try
        {
            guessedLetter = Convert.ToChar(guess);
            if (!Char.IsLetter(guessedLetter))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid Letter Choice");
            //guessLetter(guessedCharacters, word, wordToDisplay, ref numGuessesLeft);
        }
        bool repeat = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < guessedCharacters.Count; i++)
        {
            if (guessedCharacters[i] == guessedLetter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid Letter Choice");
                repeat = true;
                //guessLetter(guessedCharacters, word, wordToDisplay, ref numGuessesLeft);
            }
        }
        if (repeat == false)
        {
            guessedCharacters.Add(guessedLetter);
            numGuessesLeft -= 1;
        }
    }

    // ****** Check to see if player wants to play again. ******

    static void checkIfPlayAgain()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (y/n)");
        string playAgain = Console.ReadLine();
        if (playAgain == "n")
        {
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Wordlist.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class WordList : List<string>
{   
}
```

Comment: But I need to have the wordlist in a separate file... It´s a school assignment and that was the instruction... So if I have it in separate file, does that still work?

Comment: well then just inherit the list and be done with it I will make an update

Comment: So I need to remove the hole section "pick word" in program file? But still how do I connect the 2 files? Do I call the method from program file? Sorry I´m quite a beginner...

Comment: this line is your connection: WordList words = new WordList();

Comment: the class file is only a blueprint for creating an object

Comment: @Thomas This random method is supposed to be more 'random': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: ok wait a minute I will write the code you need and post it afterwards

Comment: I´ve tried what you said but can´t get it to work:( And the method I had for showing all words doesn´t work with this either. Ah I´m really lost of how to solve it! Please help!:)

Comment: @MUG4N Thank you so much for your help! Made my day. I have read a book on C# but it´s difficult without any guidance:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the very simple solution:

Populate your list just one time, or when ever you add any word, call this method. Code:

```
private void PopulateTheWordList()
        {
            Console.Write("\n\tAdd a word\n\n");
            WordList.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Now just call this method to get random words:

```
private string PickWord()
        {
            Random ran = new Random();
            return WordList[ran.Next(0, WordList.Count)];
        }
```

If you need to create `List` of `words` in another class, then use keyword `static`:

```
static List<string> WordList = new List<string>();
```

Now you can call it by just writing the class name, like `YourClassName.WordList`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I don´t have any file called words.txt only the 2 files program.cs and WordList.cs

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Static Class and add a method for returning your List, you will then be able to access your wordlist.

example:

```
static class WordList
{
   static List<string> words = new List<string>();

   public static  void ListOfWords()
   {
       words.Add("test");         // Contains: test
       words.Add("dog");          // Contains: test, dog
       words.Insert(1, "shit"); // Contains: test, shit, dog

       words.Sort();
       foreach (string word in words) // Display for verification
       {
           Console.WriteLine(word);
       }

   }

   public static List<string> GetWords()
   {
      return words;
   }

   public static void AddWord(string value)
   {
       words.Add(value);
   }
}
```

You would then change your switch statement to look something like this.

```
switch (MenuChoice)
{
    case 1:               
        Console.Write("\n\tAdd a word\n\n");
        var insert = Console.ReadLine();
        WordList.AddWord(insert);
        Console.Write("\n\tList of words\n\n");
        WordList.ListOfWords();                
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.Write("\n\tList of words\n\n");
        WordList.ListOfWords();
        break;

    ....
```

and your `pickWord` Method would look like this:

```
static string pickWord()
{
    string returnword = "";

    Random randomGen = new Random();
    returnword = WordList.GetWords()[randomGen.Next(0, WordList.GetWords().Count() - 1)];
    return returnword;
}
```

---

I modified your Wordlist class so that it can use a file to maintain your Words between uses of your program, just incase that is what was being asked of you.

```
static class WordList
{
    static string filePath = @"C:\temp\Word.txt";
    static List<string> words = new List<string>();
    private static void CheckFile()
    {
       //Makes sure our base words are saved to the file
       if (!File.Exists(@"C:\temp\Word.txt"))
       {
           using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
           {
               writer.WriteLine("test");
               writer.WriteLine("dog");
               writer.WriteLine("shit");
           }
       }
   }

   public static  void ListOfWords()
   {
       CheckFile();
       words.Clear();
       using (TextReader file = new StreamReader(filePath))
       {
           char[] delineators = new char[] { '\r', '\n' };
           string[] tempWords = file.ReadToEnd().Split(delineators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

           foreach (string line in tempWords)
           {
               words.Add(line);
           }

       }


       foreach (string word in words) // Display for verification
       {
           Console.WriteLine(word);

       }

   }

   public static List<string> GetWords()
   {
      return words;
   }

   public static void AddWord(string value)
   {
       CheckFile();
       using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath,true ))
       {
           writer.WriteLine(value);
       }
   }
}
```