# Retrieving a random word from a string array

Tags: c#

I have a string array containing 5 different words. How can I randomly pick one and store it in a string variable?

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Comment: Like this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800121/how-to-get-a-random-word-from-a-given-list-of-words/17800148#17800148

Comment: [You are kidding...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121649/pick-random-word-from-list).

Comment: Have you looked at the `System.Random` class? Look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Random` class:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
var idx = new Random().Next(arr1.Length);
return arr1[idx];
```

Comment: should be `arr1.Length-1`

Comment: @LukeHutton: No, the upper bound is exclusive.

Comment: Could just be `new Random().Next(arr1.Length)`, though.

Comment: @LukeHutton no it should be arr1.Length

Comment: doh, yah just saw... inclusive lower, exclusive upper http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Random rnd = new Random();
      string[] malePetNames = { "Rufus", "Bear", "Dakota", "Fido", 
                                "Vanya", "Samuel", "Koani", "Volodya", 
                                "Prince", "Yiska" };
      string[] femalePetNames = { "Maggie", "Penny", "Saya", "Princess", 
                                  "Abby", "Laila", "Sadie", "Olivia", 
                                  "Starlight", "Talla" };                                      

      // Generate random indexes for pet names. 
      int mIndex = rnd.Next(malePetNames.Length);
      int fIndex = rnd.Next(femalePetNames.Length);

      // Display the result.
      Console.WriteLine("Suggested pet name of the day: ");
      Console.WriteLine("   For a male:     {0}", malePetNames[mIndex]);
      Console.WriteLine("   For a female:   {0}", femalePetNames[fIndex]);
   }
}
```

This is an example from the documentation.

Study it, and it will be easy to adopt this to meet your needs. The idea is to generate a random index and use it to index the array
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Comment: I didn't (and I wouldn't) downvote this answer, but I suspect it's for giving the OP the proverbial fish, rather than teaching him fishing.

Comment: Hm.. I tried to encourage the OP to use the link and the example to learn more about the topic. The solution with the index indirection isn't always obvious when people are starting out with programming :-)